# Only the first SQL statement is being executed.Why is this?

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I am using the Slim PHP framework for my API. In this function, I have used two statements `$sql` and `$sql1` to execute two different queries. `$sql` is getting inserted successfully whereas `$sql1` is not. I am unable to debug this code.

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->post('/insert/work_experience', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

$user_id        = $_POST[0];
$company_name   = $_POST[1];
$start_date = $_POST[2];
$end_date       = $_POST[3];
$designation    = $_POST[4];
$vertical       = $_POST[5];
$skillstring    = $_POST[6];

$skill = unserialize($skillstring); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO work_experience (user_id, company_name, start_date, end_date, designation, vertical)
VALUES (:user_id,:company_name,:start_date,:end_date,:designation,:vertical);";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO skills (user_id, start_date, end_date, skill)
VALUES (:user_id,:start_date,:end_date,:skill);"; 

try{
    //make db object
    $db = new db();

    //connection
    $db = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id',        $user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':company_name',   $company_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start_date',     $start_date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end_date',       $end_date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':designation',    $designation);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vertical',       $vertical);

    $stmt->execute();  //This statement is being executed successfully 

    $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);

    $stmt1->bindParam(':user_id',       $user_id);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':start_date',    $start_date);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':end_date',      $end_date);


    $i=0;
    while($i<count($skill)){
        $skill1 = $skill[$i];
        $stmt1->bindParam(':skill', $skill1);
        $i++;
        $stmt1->execute(); //This statement is not being executed
    }

    echo '{"notice": {"text": "Data Added"}'; 

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
}
```

});

Comment: Does the `$skill` array actually have something in it (without which the loop would not even execute once)?  Do you get any exceptions happening?

Comment: @Zamaan what does `unserialize()` do? Does it definitely return an array with at least one element? If it returns an empty array, or something which is not an array, then the while loop will not run and $stmt1 will not execute.